# React Final Form: Is there a way to check if a particular field will be validated?

Tags: reactjs, react-final-form

I am implementing a UI such that, if there is validation on it, I should change the text color. If no validation then I leave it to take the default value. How can I know if there is validation is being applied on the Field or not?

1. `meta.valid` is not an option because by default it is valid if there is no validation
2. `meta.validating` is also not an option as it hardly takes time to validate.